# Launching QTP after key-in the logon detail

Tags: qtp

I'm trying to launch the QTP using VB code below:

```
Dim qtpApp
set qtpApp = CreateObject("QuickTest.Application")
qtpApp.Launch
```

It was working in some other environments, but in my current environment QTP would be opened only when I key-in logon detail. i.e., if we click on QTP Shortcut/QTP icon from lauch bar, it would initially open some prompt for username and password. After complete that prompt ony QTP's initial screen would be opened.

My code above does not cover this logon detail, I tried for several possibilites and searched a log. But couldn't make it possible, so can some help in this please?

Comment: What was the logon dialog -- was it the QC connect dialog? It can only be avoided by not auto-connecting to QC, or saving the user pwd and password.

Answer (score 0):

Go to File->ALM/QC Connection and enable automatic login by providing the necessaryc Credentials.

Enable the 3 checkboxes in this window also.